# Merge/synonymize [google-docs] and [google-drive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Google Docs are now part of Google Drive. Should not [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) now be a synonym of [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree, this is done.

```
updating post history, 521 rows affected
updating posts, 432 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 416 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [google-drive] and [google-docs] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
82 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late now, but I'll post as an answer anyway.

I'm not entirely convinced this was necessary - while Google is busy amalgamating things (I suspect this is only the beginning), I think there is a place for categorising questions as belonging to the file storage product ([example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27142/google-drive-image-hotlinking)) versus the document editing product ([example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31712/google-presentation-very-slow)). `google-docs` was already fairly broad since it encompassed documents, spreadsheets, presentations etc.

I know there is already a bit of a mix of terminology since the delineation isn't very clear, but I think it is something we could have lived with and worked around.

Also four hours seems a bit fast for a 500+ question change in a sleepy meta like webapps :-)

Comment: @pnuts it looks like we remapped -docs to -documents [a couple of years back](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/synonyms-for-google-drive-apps), which undid what this Q did and solves the problem, yes :-)

Comment: Sometimes it takes time, but we get there!