# Tag [google-docs] should be a synonym of [google-documents], NOT a synonym of [google-drive], please correct it

Tags: support, status-declined, tag-synonyms

I couldn't find a way to vote to remove the synonym, that was why I posted it here.

Comment: Considering Google themselves call Google Docs as Google Drive now, the synonym is corect

Comment: I must admit that this is a bit confusing. Better is to determine what exactly is meant (Google Drive or Google Documents) and edit the question accordingly. -1 for the synonym request and +1 for posting here!

Comment: See also: [Merge/synonymize google-docs and google-drive](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Docs is what Google calls their online office suite.

Google Documents is what Google calls their online word processor, which is a part of the online document suite.

Considering Google has rebranded Google Docs to Google Drive, the synonym for Google Docs to Google Drive is the correct one. Refer this previous meta post:

- [Merge/synonymize google-docs and google-drive](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/merge-synonymize-google-docs-and-google-drive?rq=1)

Comment: OK, I got. So Google Docs is not an abbreviation of Google Document! I thought so. Thank you for clarification `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. I thought that **Google Docs** is abbreviation of **Google Document** which was wrong.

As the wikipedia states:

> Documents, spreadsheets, presentations can be created with Google
>   Docs, imported through the web interface, or sent via email.

[Reference Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs)