# Synonyms for Google Drive apps

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Can we get some synonyms created? Google can't seem to make up their minds on what things should be called.

- [google-slides](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-slides) should be a synonym for [google-presentations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-presentations)
- *Google Drive* was originally *Google Docs*, but now Google Docs refers to Google Documents. Please remove [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) as a synonym for [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) and make it a synonym for [google-documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-documents)

Fortunately, [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) is already a synonym for [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

This will get the major Google Drive applications aligned with their alternative names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed.. changed/added the synonyms as you have suggested